# map(int, raw_input().split()) gets infinite input

Tags: python, loops

Here's the code:

```
a = input()
b = map(int, raw_input().split())

maxcnt=1

for k in range(0,a):
    cnt=1
    j=k+1
    while b[k]%b[j] == 0 or b[j]%b[k] == 0 :
        cnt += 1

    if maxcnt < cnt:
        maxcnt = cnt

print maxcnt
```

While giving the list values, after giving the values separated with spaces, I press enter and it still keeps getting the input. What's the issue?

Comment: It works fine for me. What did you use as inputs?

Answer (score 0):

The statement `b = map(int, raw_input().split())` is perfectly okay. The problem is that you are encountering an **infinite loop** in the later `while` part of your code. There should be some issue with the logic.

So, you are taking `modulo` of consecutive numbers in the list `b` ? So, an input like this:

`b = [1,2,3,4]`

will cause an **infinite loop**, since `1%2 == 0 or 2%1 ==0` => **True**. It is clearly an input dependent scenario.

Comment: It's not modulus, it's modulo. Modulus is the absolute of a number :)

Comment: @MoonCheesez, Thanks fixing it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows a `while` statement which does not change it's conditions while looping:

```
while (b[s] % b[j]) == 0 or
      (b[j] % b[s]) == 0:
    cnt += 1
```

As you can see here, `cnt` is not in the condition `(b[s] % b[j]) == 0 or (b[j] % b[s]) == 0`, therefore, it will just keep on incrementing `cnt` and will not stop.

What you see is an empty console (which you then thought meant it was asking for more input) which was actually just the while loop running continuously.